# element.addEventListener not adding listener

Tags: html, node.js, events, electron, addeventlistener

So I have an array of strings that will turn into buttons,

```
//At start
function acceptSuggestion() {
    console.log(`clicked`)
    console.log(this.textContent);
}
//Else where
suggestions.couldBe.innerHTML = ``;
list.suggestions.forEach(function (item) {
    let button = document.createElement(`button`);
    button.textContent = item;
    button.addEventListener(`click`, acceptSuggestion);//before append
    button.style = `text-align:center; width:50%`;
    suggestions.couldBe.appendChild(button);
    button.addEventListener(`click`, acceptSuggestion);//after append
    suggestions.couldBe.innerHTML+=`<br>`;
});
```

It creates the buttons fine
[image: List]
But clicking them does nothing.

Why is this? I know I have the event right cuz of this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

If it matters, I am using electron.js to create an webpage like application, and not a browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because of this line:
`suggestions.couldBe.innerHTML+="<br>";`

What is happening is your Browser element is generating all new fresh HTML each loop because of the `+=` on the `innerHTML`.

Basically in pseudo code:

```
var temp = suggestions.couldBe.innerHTML + "<br>;
suggestions.couldBe.innerHTML = temp;
```

This causes your element that was added via the `suggestions.couldBe.appendChild(button);`  to be converted to html, then re-parsed and all new elements created from HTML each iteration of the loop.  Because your Button event handler was created in JS; it is lost when it recreated the button from the HTML version.

You want to do this either all via JS; not mixing it.   So my suggestion would be to change this line:
`suggestions.couldBe.innerHTML+="<br>";`

to

`suggestions.couldBe.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));`